# If Radio Button is Selected Show Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Regarding to post:
[If Radio Button is Selected Show Div - 8 Radio Buttons / 8 Divs - Can this be simplified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655710/jquery-html-if-radio-button-is-selected-show-div-8-radio-buttons-8-divs)

and best answer by "Rory McCrossan"

I tried to create html file "test.html" which contains:

```
  <style type="text/css">
    .content {display: none}
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $('.trigger').click(function() {
      $('.content').hide();
      $('.' + $(this).data('rel')).show();
  });
  </script>

  <form id='group'>
      <label>
          <input type="radio" name="group1" class="sim-micro-btn trigger" data-rel="sim-micro-desktop" />
      </label>
      <label>
          <input type="radio" name="group1" class="sim-mini-btn trigger" data-rel="sim-mini-desktop" />
      </label>
      <label>
          <input type="radio" name="group1" class="sim-maxi-btn trigger" data-rel="sim-maxi-desktop" />
      </label>
      <label>
          <input type="radio" name="group1" class="sim-mega-btn trigger" data-rel="sim-mega-desktop" />
      </label>
  </form>
  <div class="billpay-internet-add-ons">
      <div class="sim-micro-desktop content">sim-micro</div>
      <div class="sim-mini-desktop content">sim-mini</div>
      <div class="sim-maxi-desktop content">sim-maxi</div>
      <div class="sim-mega-desktop content">sim-mega</div>
</div>
```

And I can see radio buttons but when I choose any then notthing happes. Any idea?

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/mLkGU/

Comment: Seems to work fine: [See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y67Yk/)

Comment: Yes, it works with Fiddle but when I try local it doesn't

Comment: Are you importing jQuery?

Comment: Works for me. Are you loading jQuery?

Comment: Guys just try do it locally on your computer and tell me if it works for you.

Comment: Sorry guys but how can I load jQuery? I thought it is javascript and it's enought to put this code between <script type="text/javascript">...</script>

Comment: I think I know your problem. First you should upload your test.html to local server (I personally use Wamp server), second you need to include this <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> in <head> of your page. Just remember, in order to import jQuery to your page, you should open it from the server, not just static html file

Comment: jQuery is not javascript.  You need to actually define it.  You can use CDN's for this:  `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js`, so would look like this:  `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: I just added this line on top of my file and it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here is a fiddle with out the use of javascript, just css. http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/UbF9a/

Comment: @maniootek Your source worked for me locally, but only if I moved the piece of Javascript to the end of the body. The way you'd written it, it was executed before the radio buttons were created in the DOM.

Comment: Make sure you have jQuery loaded and put your `.click()` event handler within `$(document).ready()` to ensure the DOM has fully loaded before you start running scripts.